# Javascript not loading in control panel

Tags: matrix, control-panel, error, jquery, javascript

I have a site running EE2.9.0 using Focus labs config set-up.

I am getting javascript errors in the control panel which are stopping Matrix and some other fields from working.

```
http://domain/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog&plugin=ee_interact.event,ee_broadcast.event,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_toggle_all,ee_navigation&file=json2,underscore,cp/global_start&v=1409223534

http://domain/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=load&file=ext_scripts

http://domain/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=datepicker,resizable,draggable,droppable&plugin=ee_url_title,tmpl,ee_table,ee_filebrowser,ee_fileuploader,markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay&file=cp/publish,cp/category_editor,cp/date,files/publish_fields,cp/publish_tabs,cp/publish_admin&v=1409223533
```

These are returning 500 Internal Server Errors in the inspector in Chrome. I am getting the same in Firefox.

It is all working fine locally and on a staging server so I guess it's something server related but I'm struggling to pin it down.

I've tried stripping everything out of htaccess but that didn't seem to help.
I've also tried various combinations of trailing slashes/no trailing slashes on theme_folder_path and theme_folder_url.

Comment: try to disable all extension which use cp_jd_end hook - you can just add $config['allow_extensions'] = 'n' into config.

Comment: So, what is the solution? I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the issue, but I do know that the session library is no longer called in cp_jd_end and messed up a few extensions I built when I upgraded to 2.9.0. Check to make sure there are no session references in any add-ons using the JS hook. If there are, load the session library by calling `$this->EE->load->library('session');`